# Seaborn Trellis Graphs in Loop

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, seaborn

Another Seaborn question for y'all:

I'm generating graphs in a loop to get all combinations of column names from two lists.

Bare-boned code sample:

```
for item1 in list1:
    for item2 in list2:
        g = sns.jointplot(item1, item2, data=data,kind='reg')
        g.savefig(item1 + "_" + item2 + '.png")
```

As is, this is great, but I have to scroll through all the images that I create.

I would like to create a multi-graph plot of this, trellis-style.

I've seen some examples of similar grids using things like FacetGrid, but I am not able to find a way to put graphs on that grid as I create them, accumulator-style, one graph for each of item1 in list1.

Is this possible? Let me know if you need more info!

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since found the answer to my question from looking at the docs.

```
for item1 in list1:
    for item2 in list2:
        g = sns.jointplot(item1, item2, data=data,kind='reg')
        g.savefig(item1 + "_" + item2 + '.png")
```

is great for generating individual pictures, but I should use pairplot to get pictures together.

For example, if I want to generate one plot for each item in list1, I would do this:

```
for item in list1:
    g = sns.pairplot(data, x_vars=list2, y_vars=[item], kind='reg')
    g.savefig("Combinations with " + item + ".png")
```